# Response.Redirect issue after Response.StatusCode sent

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, iis-7.5

I have a customer 404 error page setup (.aspx) and when it gets executed by the server I'm sending a Response.StatusCode = 404 via the code behind.  The page loads correctly with the proper info, header, footer, etc.  However, there are controls in the header or footer that do a Response.Redirect if clicked.  So if these are clicked while on the 404 page nothing happens except a querystring is added to the url like 
http://stage.mysite.com/defaudlt.aspx?404%3bhttp%3a%2f%2fstage.mysite.com%3a80%2fdefaudlt.aspx

I have a hunch that this has something to do with headers already being sent but not sure how to fix.

*Edited to add code

404 Page CS

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();      
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
}
```

Rendered Button in master page

```
<input type="submit" class="wtb-submit" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentMain_Button1" value="WHERE TO BUY" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentMain$Button1">
```

MasterPage button click event

```
 protected void btnLocator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Redirect("/locator/default.aspx");

}
```

Comment: Please show your code - enough that we can repeat the problem.  Also, the rendered HTML of the links that aren't working right would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ~ sing before your page

```
 Response.Redirect("~/locator/default.aspx");
```

hope this will work